# bash to combine all files into one in a specific directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to combine all the files of the same name ${id}.txt from the gjb2 menu, into one file (out.txt) and am having trouble:

```
 gjb2() {
printf "\n\n"
printf "What is the id of the patient getting GJB2 analysis  : "; read id
printf "Enter variant(s): "; IFS="," read -a variant

    [ -z "$id" ] && printf "\n No ID supplied. Leaving match function." && sleep 2 && return
    [ "$id" = "end" ] && printf "\n Leaving match function." && sleep 2 && return

    for ((i=0; i<${#variant[@]}; i++))
          do printf "NM_004004.5:%s\n" ${variant[$i]} >> c:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/Python27/$id.txt
    done
add2text ${id}.txt
add2out
gjb2name
}
```

command to combine:

```
add2out() {
cd 'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\annovar'
printf "NM_004004.5:%s\n" ${variant[$i]} > C:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/annovar/out.txt >> out.txt
}
```

Thank you :).

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: The out.txt as of now just has the text from the printf "NM_004004.5" repeated twice.  What am I doing wrong, why isn't the variant ($[variant[$i} being added as well?  Thank you :).

Comment: your question headline vs your text don't seem to match up. Where are you attempting to "combine all files into one"? You know about `cat * > ../all_in_one_file` ? Also, in your `add2out`, do you know about `tee`? maybe `printf ... | tee -a out.txt > C:/Users/cmccabe/Desktop/annovar/out.txt` would help you? Good luck.